# Table of contents error, using pylatex

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm getting an error with my table of contents. Rather than getting:

```
1 Section 1 -------- 1
```

I am getting

```
black1 Section 1 --------1
```

I have no idea why. I suspect it might be because I am using pylatex to compile the latex script, which looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{portrait, margin=1in,tmargin=1in}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{document}

\hfill \\ Project Name \\
Systems Performance Team \\
External Reference: XXXX \\
Internal Reference: TPREF-XXXXXXXX \\

\begin{center}
\uppercase{\Huge{Report Title}} \\
\uppercase{\Huge{Line}} \\
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Section 1}
\footnotesize

Hello, testing this document business

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect it could have something to do with you having (mis)placed `\begin{titlepage}` before `\begin{document}`, it should of course be placed after.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misplaced `\begin{titlepage}` that causes several errors, so the output is not really predictable.

Your code needs also some reshaping:

1. `hyperref` should be loaded last
2. instead of loading `colortbl` after `xcolor`, do `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`
3. `\uppercase{\Huge{text}}` is wrong; declare `\Huge` in advance and use `\MakeUppercase`; also remember that `\Huge` does not take an argument.
4. The options to `geometry` and `hyperref` are better set in a line for each one, so they're better visible

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% the correct way
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\geometry{
  portrait,
  margin=1in,
  tmargin=1in
}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black
}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}% <------  After \begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm} % or whatever

\begin{flushleft}
Project Name \\
Systems Performance Team \\
External Reference: XXXX \\
Internal Reference: TPREF-XXXXXXXX
\end{flushleft}

\vspace*{2cm} % or whatever

\begin{center}
\Huge
\MakeUppercase{Report Title} \\
\MakeUppercase{Line}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Section 1}
\footnotesize

Hello, testing this document business

\end{document}
```